# How to get line numbers of errors when using source()?

Tags: r

I am so frustrated with R not reporting the error line numbers... not even when I save my script and call it with `source()`:

```
options(show.error.locations = TRUE)
source("run.R")
# Error in `[.data.frame`(pred, , c("avgScore")) : 
#   undefined columns selected
```

I don't understand this, R many times reports line numbers but not now, even if I use:

```
source("run.R", keep.source=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R will report the error location in two different circumstances:

- During parsing, if you have a syntax error.  That's not the error you're seeing.
- If the error occurs in code that was parsed with the `keep.source=TRUE` option in effect.  Unfortunately for you, the error you are seeing is in the `[.data.frame` function, which is in the `base` package, not your `run.R` file.  R normally isn't built with `keep.source=TRUE`, so `base` package functions don't report line numbers.

However, there is still a way to see where the error happened.  After you see the error, run `traceback()`.  (If you're using RStudio, there's generally a little popup option saying `Show traceback` that does this.)

For example, when I source this file (`Untitled.R`):

```
f <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(x=1, y=2)
  df[,"z"]
}

f()
```

I get the error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , "z") : undefined columns selected
```

and `traceback()` shows

```
8: stop("undefined columns selected")
7: `[.data.frame`(df, , "z") at Untitled.R#3
6: df[, "z"] at Untitled.R#3
5: f() at Untitled.R#6
4: eval(ei, envir)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("~/temp/Untitled.R")
```

The lines 6 and 7 are the important ones, indicating that the error is in line 3 of my file.

Comment: thanks! Works for this error! But now I had an error for which it doesn't work: `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` which happened when I did `x$y` and `x` was no longer a list. Is there a way to find the correct line of these errors too?

Comment: Did you source the file containing that line?  I get the location in the first report:  `Error in x$y (from Untitled.R#3) : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: Yes! And it didn't work, but with a simple example like yours it works. I don't get it where is the problem....

Comment: I think you'll need to simplify your real code and post it if you want any suggestions.  This will probably locate the error for you so you won't need the answer by the end, but it may turn up some ideas for what to do next time...